# Nifi will run but won't open in browser- Possible error with JAVA

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am able to start and stop nifi from terminal, but I cannot get it to appear in chrome local host. I just downloaded JAVA 17.0.1 and nifi 1.14.0 so one or both may not be configured correctly. Here is an error I found in the logs-any guidance would be appreciated.

````
org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @47f0e078
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.injectSnappyNativeLoader(SnappyLoader.java:297)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:227)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:48)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.<clinit>(PutHiveStreaming.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardExtensionDiscoveringManager.getClass(StandardExtensionDiscoveringManager.java:328)
    at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.documentConfigurableComponent(DocGenerator.java:100)
    at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:65)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1126)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:159)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:303)```
````

Comment: The 1.10.0 release says that it runs on Java 11, and I don't see any mention of later JDKs in later release notes. I'd try running it on 11.

Answer (score 0):

Only Java 8 or Java 11 are supported by NiFi at this time.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system_requirements